# Humans in future sell their organs to company which collects the goods in few years

Tags: story-identification

I saw this movie probably in late 90 or early 2000, not sure how old movie was back then.

There is a corp that buys organs from people

Comment: This is a very brief description, is there anything else at all about the film you can remember that you could [edit] in? Any plot points, what happens etc.?

Comment: I'm assuming the main character sold their heart and has now decided against it, organlegging style

Comment: There were 2 similar movies around the same time.  Repo the Genetic Opera (or something like that) was one of them.  I'm sure one is what you're looking for.

Comment: Valorum - yeah he sold something and decided against it when they were about to collect, I have very little memories of this movie besides that.

Comment: @eshier sounds like a partial match, but a bit too late. Jarek, have you had the chance to check out the movie eshier suggested? The other one is [*Repo Men*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo_Men) (2010), which is still a bit too late, though.

Comment: I think it is probably Repo Men - will probably watch tomorow, the second one is not the one, but looks interesting, I will watch both, thank you!